# DRBD: Where am I losing 13% of disk space?

Tags: linux, disk-space-utilization, drbd

I have 2 `DRBD` based storage clusters. And I am somehow not able to utilize 13% of the underlying disk space. The disk in both configs is `sda4`
Server1: `sda4` size: **859G**, `drbd0` size:**788G**, `drbd0` space available with *empty disk*:**748G**
Server1: `sda4` size: **880G**, `drbd0` size:**807G**, `drbd0` space available with *empty disk*:**766G**
resource config:

```
$cat /etc/drbd.d/nfs.res
resource r0 {
    device /dev/drbd0;
    disk /dev/sda4;
    meta-disk internal;
    protocol C;

    disk {
        md-flushes no;
        resync-rate 90M;
        al-extents 3833;
        c-plan-ahead 2;
        c-fill-target 2M;
        c-max-rate 100M;
        c-min-rate 25M;
    }

    handlers {
        fence-peer "/usr/lib/drbd/crm-fence-peer.9.sh";
        after-resync-target "/usr/lib/drbd/crm-unfence-peer.9.sh";
        pri-lost-after-sb "/usr/lib/drbd/notify-pri-lost-after-sb.sh";
    }

    net {
        sndbuf-size 0;
        max-buffers 8000;
        max-epoch-size 8000;
        after-sb-0pri discard-least-changes;
        after-sb-1pri discard-secondary;
        after-sb-2pri call-pri-lost-after-sb;

        fencing resource-only;
    }


    on node1 {
        address x.x.1.1:7790;
    }
    on node2 {
        address x.x.1.2:7790;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about DRBD and you didn't provide much detail in your question about how you measured free space, but similar things happen with ext4, which most distros initialize with a 5% reserved by default: maybe your DRBD has similar default configuration?

I couldn't help noticing that the amount of missing space is more or less said 5%, if you consider DRBD size and available space...

Comment: I considered that and looked into DRBD documentation but was not able to find anything related. Also DRBD is claiming 91% of disk space, after that it's somehow blocking additional 4-5%. That is why total loss is about 13%.